# Dealing with tabular data in Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-analysis

This is an excerpt of a `file.csv` file with some tabular data

```
John,23,Paris
Alban,28,London
Klaus,27,Berlin
Hans,29,Stockholm
Julian,25,Paris
Jonathan,26,Lyon
Albert,27,London
```

The column headers for this file would be

```
firstName, age, city
```

This file is loaded in `ghci` like this

```
> :m + Data.List Data.Function Data.List.Split
> contents <- readFile "file.csv"
> let t = map (splitOn ",") $ lines contents
> mapM print $ take 3 t
["John","23","Paris"]
["Alban","28","London"]
["Klaus","27","Berlin"]
[(),(),()]
```

Now, if I want to add a `birthYear` column to those 3 columns, I can do

```
> let getYear str = show $ 2016 - read str
> let withYear = map (\(x:xs) -> x : xs ++ [getYear (head xs)]) t
> mapM print $ take 3 withYear
["John","23","Paris","France","1993"]
["Alban","28","London","UK","1988"]
["Klaus","27","Berlin","Germany","1989"]
[(),(),()]
```

This works well but what bothers me is that the `getYear` function has type `String -> String` and as such, type checking is pretty much useless here.

I could easily convert `t` into a list of tuples like `("John", 23, "Paris")` but what about if I have not 3, but 300 features (which is not that uncommon in machine learning problems)?

- What would be the best way to deal with different column types? Using tuples? Using maps?
- In case of a big number of columns, is there a way to make Haskell infer the column's types? For instance, it would detect that column 2 in the above example is `Int`, and the others are strings?
- Concerning column headers, would there be a way that one could simply access the columns by label instead of by index, so that `getYear` could be something like `2016 - column['age']` (Python example)?
- I'm used to Python's Pandas DataFrames which perform all this stuff automagically, but Haskell looks like it could perform a ton of it natively. Not sure how to do this however as of now.

Comment: Would your goal be having a lightweight data schema -- essentially a representation for a tuple type like `(Int, String, ...)` except that it would have many fields? Do you think you can access said schema somewhere? E.g., written in the csv file? Otherwise, one could guess it from the first row with some heuristics(?) This might turn out to be a nice project.

Comment: @chi kind of. However the problem with tuples is that they can contain at most 65 (or 62, don't remember exactly) elements, which makes them unpractical for this purpose.

Comment: My experience doing similar things is tuples are (almost) never the best solution. Data types in haskell are cheap, so just create a record, it will make your life much easier. Also there is the [cassava](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava) package to parse it. It even have a generic instance so you don't really need to do anything to get your csv parsed properly with the correct type.

Comment: @mb14 thanks - the data types declaration (as shown in https://github.com/hvr/cassava) are precisely one of the things I'd like to avoid - I would prefer not having to type 350 type declarations in the beginning of the file if I have 350 features - do you know if there is a way for those types to be inferred?

Comment: @Jivan that would have to occur at compile time. The only way I can think of is to use Template Haskell to generate the declaration from the CSV file header, but it seems a bit heavy.

Comment: Perhaps, if you want a more loosely typed approach, you define a `data Value = I Int | S String | ...` i.e. a "sum type" and use that for every field. There will be no static guarantees that all the CSV rows will have the same runtime "shape", but it might be better than nothing.

Comment: @Jivan I'm not sure I understand your 350 "features". You only have to do 1 type declaration per file as far as I know. Now, if you are planning to process 350 different files, with 350 different functions, the overhead of creating 1 data types per files is null.

Comment: There is also a [frame](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Frames) package which might be what you want. I've never used it.

Comment: @mb14 suppose you have three columns: `name, age, height` - with respective types `string, int, float` - that's 3 type declarations. Now imagine that you have 350 columns ( = "features" in machine learning vocabulary) like that. In the example provided by cassava, one would have to specify `data Person = Person { name :: !String, age :: !Int, height :: !Float, Feature4 :: !Int, Feature5 :: !Int, ..., Feature350 :: !Int }` etc up to 350 columns, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jivan Ok I didn't realize you add actually 350 columns in your csv. A tuple won't work indeed. There is possibly a limit in GHC but even without that, most interesting type classes have only instances for tuple up to 10 or 15 (sometime even only 5). A Map might be indeed the solution. However, why not having a record with a `feature :: [Int]` (or equivalent, Seq, Map) and write your cassava instance to fill this `feature` attributes from your 350 columns.

Comment: @mb14 thanks, I'll dig into that.

Comment: @mb14 Does Haskell impose any limits on the number of fields in a record?

Comment: @DerekMahar I wouldn't think so, but I'm not sure. It might that there is no theoritical limit but practical one (maybe the compiler can choke on BIG record). Anyway, were it to happend, you can easily solve the proble by nested records.

Comment: @mb14 Couldn't you also use nested tuples to represent the columns in each row?

Comment: @DerekMahar Yes, you could use nested tuple as well.